# How can i have text that is always float: right with a horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a top navigation section at the top of a web page and I have some content that is setup as

```
 float: right;
```

this works great except that the content part of the page is now very wide (i have to set `min-width: 1700px;`)

the  issue is now the `float: right` works great  except when i scroll to the right, its no longer on the right.

my choices are either to:

1. Make the top section `min-width:1700px` as well but them it would float right and it wouldn't be shown unless i scrolled to the right

Is there any way to have `float: "rightofMonitor"` so it would default to the right side of the monitor viewing screen but when i scrolled over horizontally it will keep moving right.

Comment: Any HTML sample to work with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this : http://jsfiddle.net/XHRkS/

use the `position:fixed;` and `right:0;`

Comment: you might want to set either the top or the bottom to sort out the position

Answer (score 2):

Forget the floating. You should set the position to `absolute` and then set the `right` to `0`.

Comment: depends on how you set up the HTML, if it is just an element hanging out by itself, the absolute positioning works, if it has a wrapper like your JSFiddle, then the fixed is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have it in a container and it is floating to the right of the container not the body. Take it out of the container and put it below the body tag. Or give it absolute positioning of `right:0;`