# How to make the Navigation bar not move when window scrolled down CSS?

Tags: css, position, navigationbar

On my website, i got the background image to stay always centered and the navigation to always stay on the same spot horizontally, so it does not matter the HORIZONTAL size, it's always on the same spot i did that by using:

```
#nav {
    list-style: none;
    position:fixed;
    right:50%;
    margin-right:155px;
    margin-top:220px;
 }
```

My issue is with the VERTICAL part. When the Window is small vertically and it gets scrolled down, the menu moves with the page, an i don't want that. I wanted to make it stay up there with the logo, but using a percentage for "top" doesn't seem to work.
I am not very familiar with javascript so if it could be don with CSS, it would be easier for me to understand!

HEEELP!

**here is my example!**

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/rafacardosoc/wQdVv/8/)

Comment: See if this is what you want: change the field `right` in the `#nav` to `auto`.

Comment: @PiLHA: right position is fine, what i wanted to change is the TOP/BOTTOM position. i dont want it to scroll with the page!

Comment: I don't see anything in example , Is i my problem? ... anyway I think you need to use 'position:relative;' next placing your div by top and right/left parameters ... Something else, I saw a little Jquery that makes hover style, It's better to use #nav:hover.

Comment: FOUND AN ANSWER!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590904/how-to-avoid-position-fixed-from-staying-on-the-screen-when-vertical-scrolling?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Change your nav class to:

```
#nav {
    list-style: none;
    position:absolute;
    right:50%;
    margin-right:155px;
    margin-top:220px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but is this what you are looking for:

```
#nav {
    list-style: none;
    position:fixed;
    left: 0;
    top:220px;
}
```

And your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wQdVv/16/

Do note that `position:fixed` on mobile is a bad idea, as support is not good and will produce strange/unwanted results. Use `static` on mobile in stead (with a media query)

Answer (score 0):

it's because

```
position:fixed;
```

that means you want your nav to move with your screen.

[you can read about positions here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

but if you want your nav to be beside your logo you should create a div and put both nav  and logo in it.

```css
.header
{
  background-color:transparent;/* you can write any color you want but in this way it gets hidden */
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  }
#nav
{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-15px;
  right:42%;
  display:inline-block;
}
ul
{
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="header"><!--div that contain both logo and nav-->
      <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" /><!--logo image-->
        <!--nav  codes here-->
        <div id="nav">
          <ul><li>nav</li></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><center><h2><p>As You can see it doesn't move with page scrolling</p></h2></center>
    </body>
  </html>
```

the code above is a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the

```
position: fixed;
```

in your CSS.

`fixed` means *stay in this part of the screen, even when scrolling*. Change it to:

```
position: absolute;
```

and the navbar will stay wherever you position it and won't move, even when scrolling.

You can read more about positioning at [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)